# Failed to append to HDFS

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, client, hdfs

I have a class that is in charge of receiving some batched data from a data source and writing the serialized content of that data to a file (always the same file). For that, first thing I do when I create an instance is checking if that file exists and create it if not. This seems to create the file without problems, but the problem comes when I try to append the serialized object to the file using the method `onOperationsBatchSynchronization`.

This is the code of the mentioned class:

```
public class HDFSSpaceSynchronizationEndpoint extends SpaceSynchronizationEndpoint {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HDFSSpaceSynchronizationEndpoint.class);
    private final String uriToFileToWrite;
    private final HDFSFileUtil hdfsFileUtil;

    public HDFSSpaceSynchronizationEndpoint(HDFSFileUtil hdfsFileUtil) {
        Validate.notNull(hdfsFileUtil);
        this.hdfsFileUtil = hdfsFileUtil;
        uriToFileToWrite = hdfsFileUtil.getUriToHdfs() + "/object-container";
        createFileIfNeeded();
    }

    private void createFileIfNeeded() {
        final String methodName = "createFileIfNeeded";
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                if (!hdfsFileUtil.fileExistsInCluster(uriToFileToWrite)) {
                    hdfsFileUtil.createFileInCluster(uriToFileToWrite);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error(methodName, "", "Error creating the file in the cluster: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOperationsBatchSynchronization(OperationsBatchData batchData) {
        final String methodName = "onOperationsBatchSynchronization";
        LOG.error(methodName, "", "Batch operation received: {}", batchData.getSourceDetails().getName());
        DataSyncOperation[] operations = batchData.getBatchDataItems();
        synchronized (this) {
            for (DataSyncOperation operation : operations) {
                try {
                    hdfsFileUtil.writeObjectToAFile((Serializable) operation.getDataAsObject(), uriToFileToWrite);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.error(methodName, "", "Error writing the object to a file in the cluster: {}", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the class in charge of interacting with the space:

```
public class HDFSFileUtilImpl implements HDFSFileUtil {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HDFSFileUtilImpl.class);
    private final static boolean DELETE_RECURSIVELY = true;
    private final String uriToHdfs;
    private final FileSystem fileSystem;

    public HDFSFileUtilImpl(HDFSConfiguration config, String uriToHdfs, String user) {
        Validate.notNull(config);
        Validate.notEmpty(uriToHdfs);
        Validate.notEmpty(user);
        this.uriToHdfs = uriToHdfs;
        try {
            fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(uriToHdfs), config.getConfiguration(), user);
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error("constructor", "", "HDFSFileUtilImpl constructor failed: {}", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getUriToHdfs() {
        return uriToHdfs;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeObjectToAFile(Serializable obj, String fileUri) throws   IOException {
        Validate.notNull(obj);
        Validate.notEmpty(fileUri);
        FSDataOutputStream out;
        if (!fileExistsInCluster(fileUri)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File with URI: " + fileUri + " does not exist in the cluster");
        }
        out = fileSystem.append(new Path(fileUri));
        byte[] objByteArray = getBytesFromObject(obj);
        out.write(objByteArray);
        out.close();
    }

    private byte[] getBytesFromObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
        byte[] retByteArray = null;
        // try/catch used only to be able to use "try with resources" feature
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);) {
            out.writeObject(obj);
            retByteArray = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        return retByteArray;
    }

     @Override
     public void createFileInCluster(String uriOfFile) throws IOException {
          Validate.notEmpty(uriOfFile);
          fileSystem.create(new Path(uriOfFile));
     }

    @Override
    public boolean fileExistsInCluster(String uri) throws IOException {
        Validate.notEmpty(uri);
        boolean result = false;
        result = fileSystem.exists(new Path(uri));
        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

The data source has three connections established with my component, and the method `onOperationsBatchSynchronization` is getting called in a concurrent way. That's why the synchronization blocks are used, but even with them I am getting the following exception from the logs:

```
   10:09:23.727  ERROR  - onOperationsBatchSynchronization
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Failed to create file [/object-container] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1587728611_73] for client [127.0.0.1], because this file is already being created by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1972611521_106] on [127.0.0.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2636)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2462)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2700)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2663)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:559)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:388)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
```

So what could be the problem here? I have some unit tests (more like integration, since they rely on a running Hadoop setup) and all the methods on `HDFSFileUtilImpl` are working correctly and giving expected results.

EDIT: I just tried to write files in the cluster instead of appending to the same file and it works fine. So I would discard any permission problem.

Comment: I think there is some permissions problem due to which its unable to create a file

Comment: But it is able to create the file though. Doing some testing, I tried creating files instead of just appending, and it is creating new files without any problem. I'll edit the post to tell this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got rid of the error. Apparently it is mandatory to close the `FSDataOutputStream` that is returned when you call `create` from `filesystem`.

That being said, this is how the method `createFileInCluster` from **HDFSFileUtilImpl** is implemented now:

```
@Override
 public void createFileInCluster(String uriOfFile) throws IOException {
      Validate.notEmpty(uriOfFile);
      FSDataOutputStream out = fileSystem.create(new Path(uriOfFile));
      out.close();
 }
```

Comment: does this really append to an existing file? I found conflicting information about whether appending to a file has been reintroduced in hadoop after it's been ousted circa 2009.

Comment: No, this code only points to what is wrong in the code presented on top. The problem was that the file wasn't closed after creation, but the code that appended to a file is still the same as in the initial code. Look at the method called `writeObjectToAFile`

Comment: Actually I find nothing really about a method writeObjectToAFile of hdfsFileUtil, on Google.

Comment: When I told you to look at the method `writeObjectToAFile` I meant to look at the method with this name defined above. All the code above is created by me, and the only reference to Hadoop's api is when I use the objects FileSystem, FSDataOutputStream and Path. Please take a look to the before mentioned method and you'll see that to append you only need to call `fileSystem.append(Path)`. Make sure you close `FSDataOutputStream` when you finish or you'll have the same problem that I had.